# How to add the value of a data itemid to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

The situation is as follows. In the picture are two green buttons "Naar dit adres verzenden", which means "send to this address". Normally when someone clicks on these buttons, the user goes to a particular URL. But when someone clicks on the button the value must be passed to the class "customNextStep". This class belongs to the bottom button "Volgende", which means "next".

**Click on the link: http://postimg.org/image/dlgz5ijuj/ to see the printscreen.**

I already have been able to retrieve the value of the data item-id of the "send to this address" button. But I do not know how I can pass on this into "customNextStep" class. I do know I should use the following:

```
$('.customNextStep').attr('href');
```

but do not know exactly how.

The code I have so far is the following:

```
//get item id on address click
    if ($('.customNextStep').length) {

        $('.button-1').on("click", function (event) {
            //alert("event prevented");
            event.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).attr('data-itemid'));
        });

      .... ?????
    }
```

html "send to this address" button:

```
<input type="button" value="@T("Checkout.ShipToThisAddress")" data-itemid="@item.Id" class="button-1 select-shipping-address-button"  onclick="" />
```

html "next" button:

```
<a class="customNextStep" href=""> 
    <input type="button" name="nextstep" value="volgende" class="button-1 billing-adress-next-step-button" /> 
</a>
```

Comment: how does the html look like?

Comment: The HTML is as following:                 <a class="customNextStep" href="">
                    <input type="button" name="nextstep" value="volgende" class="button-1 billing-adress-next-step-button" />
                </a>

Comment: but in this HTML the button doesn't have a `data-itemid` attribute ... where does it come from?

Comment: and make sure you want button inside anchor, click on button would trigger click on anchor either.

Comment: @devnull69 Thats right. The top buttons contain a data-itemid but the bottom one dont. I just added the HTML code for both.

Comment: what should happen for the buttons that don't have `data-itemid`?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('.button-1').on("click", function (event) {
    //alert("event prevented");
    event.preventDefault();
    var itemid = $(this).attr('data-itemid');
    $(this).parent(".customNextStep").attr("href", itemid); 

    //Used an instance of 'this' above in case multiple customNextStep classes
    //$(".customNextStep").attr("href", itemid);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Save it using `data()`:

```
$('.customNextStep').data({ itemId: $(this).attr('data-itemid') });
```

Then you can fetch it like this:

```
var itemId = $('.customNextStep').data('itemId');
```